# Need to extract plain text from the string containing html entities and elements using php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$string = "&lt;h2&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;OutlineElement Ltr SCX116040423&quot; style=&quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 8px; font-weight: normal;&quot;&gt; &lt;p class=&quot;MsoNormal&quot;&gt;Residents of the northeast are discovering that Branford Hall has become one of the fastest and most effective ways to begin a high growth career.&lt;o:p&gt;"

$string = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$string);
```

I need the out as plain text:

> Residents of the northeast are discovering that Branford Hall has become one of the fastest and most effective ways to begin a high growth career.

please help me in correcting the preg_replace regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has some built-in functions that should be more convenient for this:

```
$string = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string));
```